# Has anyone had studied the Riemann hypothesis with non-standard models?

Tags: logic, reference-request, model-theory, riemann-hypothesis, nonstandard-models

In symbolic logic, non-standard numbers is common nomenclature for a model of numbers which satisfies the axioms of some arithmetical system, but doesn't consist of what people would normally think of as numbers. For instance, a 'number' which is its own successor is a non-standard number, and so are the pair of 'numbers' $a$ and $b$ which are each others successor (these can be considered in $Q$, Robinsons arithmetic).

I was wondering if anyone had conducted research into the Riemann hypothesis using non standard numbers, and if so, what the results tell us. Is there anything interesting to learn from this endeavour, was the Riemann hypothesis found to be false in certain non-standard models? If so, what did these models look like?

Comment: Have you seen [Fake Integers for which the Riemann Hypothesis fails](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/283172/fake-integers-for-which-the-riemann-hypothesis-fails?rq=1) on MO?

Comment: I'd say there is no hope to get anywhere using non-standard numbers. After all, the standard model of PA is uniquely different from non-standard models of PA. For one, it is the unique computable model of PA! Then again, I don't know enough to be sure, so all I'm going to say is this comment. =)